# How to add prefix to some controllers using annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing

I have at the moment two controllers.

- `GitlabAuthController`
- `UserController`

I need to add the path prefix `api` to `UserController` only.

Before I was trying following at `annotations.yaml` file:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: api
```

But this adds the prefix to all my controllers.

Is there any way I can add the exception for the `GitlabAuthController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create different directories/namespaces for the different types of controllers.

Then you can do:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

api_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Api
    type: annotation
    prefix: api
```

Routes defined on the `Api` namespace would get the `/api/` prefix, while the other routes would remain unaffected.

You can check the generated routes are fine by executing `bin/console debug:router`.

Comment: Do i need to create a folder Api inside the Controller folder?

Comment: If you are going to use the above configuration, yes. And the controllers you put in there should be in the `App\Controller\Api` namespace.